# Laravel Eloquent put all rows returned that have a column value of 0 at the end no matter the sorting

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have a builder query that pulls info depending on info entered. The main tables are hotels and rates. The user can sort the results with price high to low and price low to high. I need to put all results that return 0 ( some rate date ranges have place holders with 0 as the price ) or hotels that dont have rates at the end of the results no matter what. How can I handle making those both show up at the end regardless of the sorting. I have the below as where I am now but this doesnt handle things if it doesnt exist only if its 0 but it also doesnt handle putting the results at the end.

One more thing, Im using pagination or else I would just do a foreach and reorder them.

```
$builder->select('hotels.id','hotels.main_image','hotels.sleeps','hotels.bathrooms','hotels.destination_id','hotels.hotel_name','hotels.slug','hotels.summary','hotels.sleeps','hotels.bedrooms',DB::raw('CASE WHEN max(rates.nightly_rate) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE max(rates.nightly_rate) END AS price_high'),DB::raw('CASE WHEN min(rates.nightly_rate) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE min(rates.nightly_rate) END AS price_low')
->leftJoin('rates', 'hotels.id', '=', 'rates.hotels_id');
```

Comment: Have you tried `orderBy('column_name', 'asc');`?

Comment: This will put then at the beginning or end I always want just the null values to show up at the end

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to enforce records where `nightly_rate` is `0` or `null` to be ordered last in order by clause.

A clause like `rates.nightly_rates = 0 or rates.nightly_rate IS NULL ASC` will ensure that matched records where this condition is `FALSE` are ordered first before records where it is `TRUE`.

```php
$builder
->
//...
->orderByRaw('rates.nightly_rate = 0 OR rates.nightly_rate IS NULL ASC');
```

Comment: I tried this but it didnt work. If I do just orderBy('price_low','desc') that groups all the NULL values on top and I could put them on bottom obviously by using asc but then the highest value shows on top. I was it to always just put the NULL on bottom regardless of any other sort value.

Comment: Oh, if this is for `price_low` and only when it's null, change the clause to `orderByRaw('price_low IS NULL ASC')`

Comment: The problem with this is price_low is an alias so it wont work, I keep getting the error you SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1247 Reference 'price_low' not supported (reference to group function)